# How to install PHP in IIS 7.5, Windows Server 2008 R2 (64bits)

Tags: php, windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7.5

In http://windows.php.net/downloads I couldn't find any x64 built for download. Further I have to choose among "Thread Safe" and "Non Thread Safe" with no explanation whether one is safer than the other or it performs better. The install.txt inside the available ZIPs for download seems out-dated an it doesn't mention anything about this.

In the installation manual found in the PHP site they don't say a word about it either...

Another doubt is once I know what to download (and why), should it be setup as a FastCGI module or as an ISAPI extension?

Answer (score 2):

You could install the Microsoft Web Platform. Its just a couple of clicks and everything is configured correctly and ready to run!!
It includes many web applications, frameworks, and samples, and it gives you the possibility to add anything that you want trough a selection.
The url to download is www.asp.net/downloads
pd: of course the PHP framework is included, hehehe don't get confused just because is from Microsoft.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but Do you think is it okay installing it in a production server or is it just for development porpoises? Further, I already have IIS 7.5 working on the 2008 R2, I'm afraid installing it would mess the current configuration, isn't it?

Comment: It detects that you have already installed IIS and don't mess up anything, only it offers you in a clickable menu more options and capabilities for your server.